# generate random sample with specific distribution

Tags: r, random, dataframe

I like to generate a random set from values in one column of my data frame that should have a mean of like 82723 and I want to print the rows of the data frame that I took as sample.
I used this code but it sounds it does not work.

```
 while(x<-sample(negative_set$V4, size=91)) {
 +  if (mean(x)==821800:821700)print
```

Thanks

My data is like this:

```
    V1       V2     V3      V4      V5
1   chr1    752751  753092  7603    ENSG00000240453.1
2   chr1    752751  755214  2463    ENSG00000177757.1
3   chr1    761586  762902  1316    ENSG00000225880.4
4   chr1    879584  879955  19695   ENSG00000187634.6
5   chr1    879584  894689  15105   ENSG00000188976.6
6   chr1    934342  935552  1210    ENSG00000188290.6
7   chr1    1167629 1170421 2792    ENSG00000176022.3
8   chr1    1340841 1341132 291     ENSG00000264293.1
9   chr1    1370241 1378262 8021    ENSG00000179403.10
10  chr1    1550795 1551175 2037    ENSG00000272106.1
11  chr1    1550795 1565990 15195   ENSG00000197530.8
12  chr1    1592939 1594063 3277    ENSG00000272004.1
13  chr1    1592939 1624167 31228   ENSG00000189339.7
```

the output should be in the same format but with the mean of 82800 of the V4 column.

Comment: I think that nobody welcome you to Stack Overflow... Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that your questions are about related to [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/). But if I understood well you want to print the rows of a sample data that their mean is equal to one value, or between some values. Is that true?
Could you provide how should be the output for the data given?

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes you understood correctly. The out put should be like the input but V4 mean of the values specify the rows that I have to have.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to say what qualifies as "random" when you put a constraint on the output. For example, you might generate `n` samples, calculate the mean $mean_n$, and then locate some row whose `V4` value is  $ n * (82800-mean_n) $ .    Which might well not be achievable, given your actual `V4` dataset.

Perhaps what you really want is:
1) calculate `mean(V4)` 
2) if that value is less than 82800, randomly **remove** some rows where `V4< 82800` 
3) if that value is greater than 8200, randomly **remove** some rows where `V4 > 82800`

The code to do that should be pretty simple: just grab subsets of your matrix and have at them.